# making link targeted to the iframe, only open in the iframe and not over the page

Tags: html, iframe

The problem I have is that I am making a page where I have several buttons in one page with one iframe where they all can open the link in the iframe. The code I'm using...

link: `<a href="#" traget="myIframe">link</a>`
iframe code: `<iframe src="#" name="myIframe"></iframe>`

This code works great but if I add the page i want to get to, `<a href="http://192.168.0.1/" target="myIframe">modem</a>`, if I click on the link "modem" the page will open partially in the iframe before loading in the same page but over it like a new tab.

Comment: post the screenshots of the web page and relevant code for others to analyze

Comment: Download the HTML file <a href="https://www.mediafire.com/?2i4i5foqbsm988r">here</a> its only 2 KBs. if you run it through chrome you'll be able to see it because all the CSS I use is online, the link https://192.168.0.1/ and the http://192.168.2.1/ will most possibly not work for you.